# degrees of freedom should be 'k-p-1'... why??

Tags: poisson-distribution, chi-squared

In the goodness of fit test of Poisson distribution, the degrees of freedom should be
$$k - p - 1$$
which means,

ν = (number of categories after pooling) − (number of parameters estimated) − 1

.
for example, if I have datatable of 5 categories, and I'm testing if this data is on poisson distribution with the mean of $\lambda$.
Then the degrees of freedom would be 3.

But why??
I can't find the proof or explanation of why it should be like this, from nowhere.
I tried to find it for all day but couldn't find. So I request you for help.
Why is it? or where is the proof?

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, are you asking why there's a correction of $p - 1$ from the ostensible degrees of freedom $k$, why the result isn't just $k - p$, or how to derive the degrees of freedom in the first place?

Comment: @anomaly  I first learned DF is usually  k-1. Because if you know to the k-1th element, you can automatically figure out the last one, so the last one has no freedom.
 But in case of Poisson distribution test, it is k-p-1. And I'm asking why the 'p' came in.

Comment: There's a proof of sorts on [pp.106-7](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.212877/page/n114/mode/1up) of Stuart and Kendall's *The Advanced Theory of Statistics*, where it's done for an *arbitrary* distribution, not merely the Poisson.  You need to be aware, however, that the distribution of the chi-squared statistic is only *approximately* a chi-squared distribution with the given degrees of freedom, and you need a sufficiently large sample for the approximation to be useable.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have 5 categories. We derive two things from it. first) poisson mean $\lambda$ from it. second) we derive 'expected frequency' from it, summation of it makes 100%.
So, it means we have two simultaneous equations.
As we get 5-2(=3) of the Pearson residuals of each categories, we can automatically know the other 2 pearson residuals. Because there're two unknown left, and two simultaneous equations. If you calculate the equations, you get remaining two pearson res.
That's why  degrees of freedom is 'k-2',  not 'k-1'.